# Refresh an Activity frequently to update textview android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, refresh

i am developing an android application where in i have an activity consisting of a text view which is fetching the value from a database every 5 minutes. I want the textview to be updated with the value automatically,each time when the value is fetched. Basically I need to refresh my activity every 5 minutes. I dont want to use

```
 startActivity(new Intent(Activity.this, Activity.class));
 finish();
```

Please Help! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

When you set the text in a Android `TextView` it gets refreshed automatically (the `setText()` method in `TextView` calls invalidate internally). 
So you just need to set the text (from the UI thread) whenever you get new value from your DB (a common way for fetching the value from a background thread and then update it from the UI thread is to use Android's `AsyncTask`).

Answer (score 1):

At time of fetching value from database.
same time execute this below code.

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            YOURTEXTVIEW.setText("SET VALUE HERE");
        }
    });
```

this will update your value.